# pyephem sun apparent-diameter

Tags: sun, pyephem

I am using PyEphem to compute Right ascension and declinaison of the sun in order to determine the astronomic azomut of a target with a theodolite.

As I cannot aim at the center aof the sun with my theodolite, I need to correct the azimut of the sun from the apparent diameter of the sun. Is there a way to get it from PyEphem ?

best regards, 
JB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does  not appear to be about programming. Perhaps https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit?

Comment: I is a question about pyephem toolbox use, not really astronomy.

Answer (score 0):

The PyEphem documentation mentions the word "diameter" in its definition of the `.radius` of a body — search this page for the phrase "diameter":

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html

Can you use half of that angle to correct the azimuth?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

It seems to give a correct value.

Yesterday I found another way to do it. The body has also a earth-distance attribute. As the diameter of the sun is known, it is easy to calculate the apparent diameter

see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taille_apparente for the formula.